# How to specialize only some members of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

Code:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
  void f1() {};
  void f2() {};

};

template<>
struct A<int> {
  void f2() {};
};


int main() {
  A<int> data;
  data.f1();
  data.f2();
};
```

### ERROR:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:16: error: 'struct A<int>' has no member named 'f1'
```

Basically, I only want to specialize one function and use the common definition for other functions. (In actual code, I have many functions which I don't want to specialize).

How to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider moving common parts to a base class:

```
template <typename T>
struct ABase
{
    void f1();
};


template <typename T>
struct A : ABase<T>
{
    void f2();
}  


template <>
struct A<int> : ABase<int>
{
    void f2();
};
```

You can even override `f1` in the derived class. If you want to do something more fancy (including being able to call `f2` from `f1` code in the base class), look at the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 10):

Would this help:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
  void f1()
  {
    // generic implementation of f1
  }
  void f2()
  {
    // generic implementation of f2
  }
};

template<>
void A<int>::f2()                                                               
{
  // specific  implementation of f2
}
```

Comment: This is how I would do it. A notable possibility is, if f2() should be specialized for each typename T, it could be also just declared inside the class (not implemented). This has the added benefit of compile-time check of implementation existence for given T (if it is not implemented, linker will complain.)

Answer (score 2):

When we declare specializations for a template class, we must also define all its members, even those exactly equal to the generic template class, because there is no **inheritance** of members from the generic template to the specialization. So, in your specialization you have to implement `void f1();` too.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a workaround/syntax to avoid repeating code? (apart from `#define` of course).